# epub_viewer Package Release Build Crash

Tags: flutter, epub

I am developing an app with epub_viewer package and i set the app in release mode. Android app crashing on start if i use epub_viewer package. I'm sure i did everything right. By the way it works in debug mode. I opened a github issue but I couldn't find anything, maybe i can find help here. I tried all packages in pub dev but none of them worked properly. I would be very grateful if you have a working package or a different method to suggest.

```
            EpubViewer.setConfig(
                themeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                identifier: "iosBook",
                scrollDirection: EpubScrollDirection.ALLDIRECTIONS,
                allowSharing: true,
                enableTts: true,
                nightMode: false
                );

            EpubViewer.locatorStream.listen((locator) {
              debugPrint(
                  'LOCATOR: ${EpubLocator.fromJson(jsonDecode(locator))}');
            });

            EpubViewer.open(ePubUrl);
```

Comment: have you done that: minifyEnabled false & shrinkResources false

(According to Readme -> Note: Please add this to the release build type in your app build.gradle to avoid crashes on android release builds)

Comment: Yes i know it and i added it to my project, it keeps crashing again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dealing with this problem for a long time and finally i realized my packages were conflicting.

***epub_viewer*** and ***adapty_flutter*** package were not working at the same time in release mode. To solve this, just add the code below in your **app level build.gradle**

[The issue of my problem is attached.](https://github.com/adaptyteam/AdaptySDK-Flutter/issues/50)

```
flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation ..

    // Add this lines app level build.gradle
    implementation('androidx.appcompat:appcompat') {
    version {
        strictly '1.2.0'
        }
    }
    implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.5.0'
    // Your problem will be solved.
}
```